# Wordpress pagination doesn't show on category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need some help with WordPress pagination.

I'm trying to paginate all posts in my categories pages. I've added at the end of the loop the `paginate_links()` function but nothing appears in the front-end.

This is the code I use for displaying all "Design" posts:

```
<div role="main">
  <h3 class="page-title">RECENT POSTS IN DESIGN</h3>
    <div id="full-post-list" class="row between-xs margin-category-title">
        <?php
        if( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        $args = array(
                'offset' => 1,
                'posts_per_page' => 21,
                'cat'            => $cat,
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'post_not_in'    => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
                    );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {  
            $query->the_post();      
            get_template_part( 'content', 'latest' );
                    }
                    }   
                }
                ?>
    </div>      
    <div id="pagination">
        <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The stranger thing is that if I type in the brower URL bar mysite.com/category/design/page/2 I don't see a 404 error but I display always the first page (and the pagination links are always hidden).

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameters to this function like this, total page get from $query:

```
echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
```

or defind global $wp_query, it will auto paginate with default params:

```
<?php
global $wp_query
        if( is_category() ) {
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thak you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've passed the parameters you suggested me in the paginate_link function, but pagination is still hidden...

Comment: Passing some parameters to paginate_link add pagination in the index.php file. This doesn't work on other pages templates (category.php, archive.php, etc.). In all pages I always use the same loop.

Comment: sure, wp is not smart as you think. I think you should try this to sure wp pagination work. Change url to http://path/to/category?cat=cat_id&paged=current_page, change offset to paged. The page is always display the first page because you set offset = 1, means display from offset to posts_per_page. You should read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Comment: how to get current page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Getting_Current_Pagination_Number